# How do I change the color of a word that was replaced from the original string?

Tags: objective-c, colors, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

For example, there is an NSString called "input" that converts what the user types into the text view into an NSString.

```
NSString *input = inputTextField.text;
```

So "input" depends on whatever the user types in. Now, the following code is used to change the word that the user puts, to change it into another word. This only happens after pressing a "Convert" button.

```
input = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(?wi)\\bHello!\\b" withString:@"greetings!" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

There are over 500 words that will get replaced automatically depending on what the user types in. After it goes through all the scanning, this is the code at the end. It makes the correct auto capitalization.

```
NSMutableString *input2 = [input mutableCopy];
NSString *pattern = @"(^|\\.|\\?|\\!|\\.\"|\\!\"|\\?\")\\s*(\\p{Letter})";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:input options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange r = [result rangeAtIndex:2];
    [input2 replaceCharactersInRange:r withString:[[input substringWithRange:r] uppercaseString]];
}];
```

So you can see that the "input" is made into a copy and now becomes "input2." The replaced input is what comes out on another text view. like this:

```
_outputTextField.text = input2;
```

And this words fine. If I put, "Hello! How are you?" it will make it into "Greetings! How are you?" My problem is, on the output text view, I want that whatever word changed from the ORIGINAL writing, to become red so the user knows what changed.

I tried this, but that doesn't do anything.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutable = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:input2];
    [mutable addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, [input2 length])];
```

Another approach I tried is adding:

```
if (input != input2) {
//Above code here.
}
```

and inside I added the above code but it doesn't do anything. The easiest approach I see is something like this, if the input (original) doesn't match the input2, then make it change the color what doesn't match.

Comment: Have you tried creating the replacement string as an `NSAttributedString` and using that instead of the immediate @"Greetings!"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Because the "greetings" is the word that replaces the other word. Do you mean make it into an NSAttributedString and then color it red? If I do that, every word that is "greetings" will turn red, even one that the user put in himself. I don't want it to do that. Just the words that changed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new **NSMutableAttributedString *newMAS** .
Then do your parsing of the original string and append segments to the newMAS string, from either the original string, or the replacement text. At the same time you append the replacement text, also set the font attribute for that part of the NSAttributedString, using code like this:

```
[newMAS addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                       value:[NSColor redColor]
                       range:rangeOfReplacementText];
```

Or, you could create a NSMutableAttributedString for the replacement text and set its color as above, then just append that to newMAS as you go, interleaving segments of the original string without the attribute and this attributed replacement text, using methods to append NSString or NSAttributedString onto an NSMutableAttributedString. Useful methods include:

```
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)range;
- (void)replaceCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;
- (void)appendString:(NSString *)aString;
- (void)appendAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrString;
```